# Question regarding Hamiltonian paths in bipartite graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

Bipartite Graph with partition $V$ = $X $$\quad\cup Y $.

Suppose graph $G$ is not Hamiltonian but has a Hamiltonian path.

Is it possible for $|X|$ = $|Y|$?

From what I understand this shouldn't be possible if $G$ is not hamiltonian.

I am confused on this idea because my book does not go over Hamiltonian paths at all and mainly focuses on circuits/cycles.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All paths are bipartite. In particular, a path has a Hamiltonian path; namely, itself. Consider the path on 5 vertices. It has parts of size 2 and 3 respectively.

Edit: In light of your clarification, take a perfect matching on $2n$ vertices. The parts have equal size but the graph is not connected. So therefore, not Hamiltonian. Nor does it have a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: Are you say |X| = 2 and | Y| =3?  I can obviously see the hamiltonian Path if that was the case but I was asking if the bipartite graph is not hamiltonian is it possible for |X|=|Y|?

Comment: See my edit. Does this clarify?

Comment: I think I understood what you were saying and I believe I came up with my own solution based on yours.

Answer (score 0):

Let G be bipartite and have a hamiltonian Path but G is not hamiltonian.  If $|X|$=$|Y|$ then set $X$ and set $Y$ have the same number of vertices.  We can show a hamiltonian Path by starting at a vertex $u$ in $X$ and end at a vertex $w$ in $Y$.  Such that u1,w1,...,wn. Thus a hamiltonian Path as long as all vertices have been transversed in alternating fashion.

I believe this shows it's possible.

Comment: You are assuming what you are trying to prove. “Let G be bipartite and have a Hamiltonian path...” Why are you then proving that G has a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: I wasn't proving anything.  I was just stating my thought process of why it should work.